# Print a report Multiple times, (SSRS reporting services)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am currently working on SSRS reports 2008 displaying them in Website created in VS 2010 i.e., ASP.NET 4.0 C#.


My current issue is I have a report with only a Letterhead on it. And this report **page**  needs to be printed multiple times based on the value in  ***number of pages*** *TextBox* as shown [image]

To be a bit descriptive: 
When the user enters the value in ***Number of Pages***  *TextBox*  and clicks on this **Print button** icon, he/she lands on the page with ***ReportViewer control*** on it, displaying the report.This report has only a letterhead in the PageHeader of the report and here this report will be printed by clicking the *default* print button of ReportViewer control.
 But, I am unable to figure out, how to print this report page **as many times** as there will be the value in the ***No of Pages***  *TextBox* (as shown in the fig.) 

 (The Letterhead of the company to be shown in report is retrieved from database through a Stored Procedure)

I tried a lot of Googling but to no avail.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand for me. You interchange "Number of Pages" and Number of Copies - perhaps you just mean the latter? Can you review your question, try to clarify a bit more?

Comment: @Jeroen I've changed the language of question and tried to make it simple, pls have a look at it

Comment: Aye, now it makes more sense! I'll second @JoaoLeal's answer then, that seems like it would do the trick.

Comment: @Jeroen But I tried Joao-Leal's answer but it is showing some errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new report. 
This report should have 1 parameter called "number of copies" (or equivalent).
It should also have a Tablix with 1 column and no borders, inside the cell insert a sub report pointing to the report with the letterhead.

Your dataset query should be something like this:

```
WITH dataset AS (
   SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ALL 
   SELECT ID + 1 FROM dataset WHERE ID < @Param
)
SELECT ID 
FROM dataset --edit: obviously I was missing the table
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Then on your tablix, use this dataset, group by ID and on the group properties select "Page Breaks"->"Between each instance of a group".

If I understood your question correctly, this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest. I tried to do the same but I am getting an error : "Invalid column name 'ID'."

Comment: I even made on field name with name ID but to no avail. Can you suggest where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Where exactly is the error? can you run this query on management studio?

Comment: Joao The error 'Invalid column name 'ID'. is in line itself "SELECT ID"

Comment: That's because I'm an idiot and made a syntax error, please see the updated query above.

Comment: yes with some minor changes it **REALLY DID THE TRICK** Thank you very much !

Comment: @JoaoLeal, I tried this trick and partly working for me. Do not know why it is generating the blank pages in between when exported or printed the report. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you create a new question? The blank pages could be coming from the sub-report

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Joao's solution (thanks for that) you can also do it without a subreport by joining the counter table to the actual data you want to display in the dataset.

1. Add a Copies integer parameter with a default value of 1
2. Update your dataset to include the counter and join

   ```
    -- Generate a table with @Count rows
    WITH dataset AS (SELECT 1 AS Copy UNION ALL SELECT Copy +   1 AS Expr1 FROM dataset AS dataset_2 WHERE  (Copy < @Copies))
    SELECT * FROM dataset INNER JOIN (

    -- The primary data to repeat

    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @IdParam

    -- End

    ) d ON 1=1 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
   ```
3. Add/update your row group to group on [Copy]

   [image]
4. Set the row group page breaks to 'between each instance'

   [image]